# jQuery removeScript function for removing a javascript page

Tags: jquery, get

After using `$.getScript` to get some javascript I now want to remove this script. How can this be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *remove* a script that has already been loaded. There's no such concept. You will have to adapt this script so that it behaves as you expect it to depending on some runtime conditions. So for example if this script executes some action, you will have to modify this script so that it executes this action based on some conditions you specify. This way you can control how this script behaves.